# jQuery blur event with ID and value

Tags: jquery, plugins, editor, blur, jqte

I want to use the 'blur' event in the jQuery text plugin.
http://jqueryte.com

```
$ ('textarea'). jqte ({
blur: function (elem) {
// ID textarea?
// Content editor?
}
});
```

The function of the blur, I would like to determine the content and the ID of the textarea.

Can you help me with an idea?

Comment: try like this $('#area_name').blur(function() { }

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't look like the `blur` event is passing any arguments to the callback you might have to do something like

```js
$("textarea").each(function(idx, elem) {
  $(this).jqte({
    blur: function() {
      console.log('blur', this, arguments);
      console.log(elem.id);
      $('#log').append('<div>' + elem.id + '</div>')
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-te/1.4.0/jquery-te.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-te/1.4.0/jquery-te.js"></script>

<div id="log"></div>
<textarea id="t1"></textarea>
<br />
<textarea id="t2"></textarea>
<br />
<textarea id="t3"></textarea>
<br />
```