# jQuery Text Editor (jqte), using change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, jqte

I am trying to write some code for `change()` event using **jQuery Text Editor (jqte)**, I have two functions which give jqte functionality to textarea's

One for editors loaded with JavaScript, when clicking some elements in a page:

```
function onLoadEditor(){
    jQuery(".comment-editor").jqte({
        // some jqte params, such as fsize: false,indent: false...
        change: function(){ observeEditor(); }
    });
}
```

And other, generic function, for pages with one single editor

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".comment-editor").jqte({
        // some jqte params, such as fsize: false,indent: false...
        change: function(){ observeEditor(); }
    });
});
```

I want to access the id of the concrete textarea (all textareas in the page have an id) which has fired the `change()` event

How should I write `observeEditor()` function to achieve this? Or... how I should define the function in jqte change property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading this [jQuery blur event with ID and value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082631/jquery-blur-event-with-id-and-value) I have solved it, with following code (simplified)

```
function onLoadEditor(){
    jQuery(".comment-editor").each(function(idx, elem) {
        jQuery(this).jqte({
            // some jqte params, such as fsize: false,indent: false...
            change: observeEditor(elem.id),
    });
}

jQuery(function() {
    onLoadEditor();
});
```

But now I have another problem...

As you can read in the original question, `onLoadEditor()` is called when clicking some elements in a page. Then another javascript function `jsComment()` is called, builds a form (with a `textarea.comment-editor` field included) and it is rendered this way

```
function jsComment(){
    ...
    var form = '<div class="comments_wrapper ... ';
    jQuery(form).insertAfter(some_element).fadeIn('fast');
    onLoadEditor();
}
```

Problem is `change()` event is being fired only once, when form fades in, while the idea is the opposite, event should fire when user adds some text, not when appearing... Any tips?

**UPDATE**
After reading [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) I have solved it this way

```
function onLoadEditor(){
    jQuery('.comment-editor').each(function(idx, elem) {
        jQuery(this).jqte({
            // some jqte params, such as fsize: false,indent: false...
        });
        jQuery(document).on('change', 
            jQuery('.comment-editor'), 
            function(){ 
                observeEditor(elem.id); 
            }
        );
    });
}

jQuery(function() {
    onLoadEditor();
});
```

Although finally I am not using `change()` event, as it was being fired constantly. Performing better with `keyup()` & `paste()`, for instance